# C# When the mouse cursor hovering in ControlLabel it will show up list of items? What kind of control is that?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Label Control then when mouse cursor is hovering around it for about 1second, it will show list of items in text format(the items are either plain text or it is also a control). It's like in the website Home/Contact Us/About Us/Help. What kind of control i'm going to use?

Like for example. www.ebay.com. Under "My Ebay", it will shows you the items, eg Summary/Bids/List/Messages...etc...

Comment: Ummmm... `ToolTip`?

Comment: not a tooltip either, it it a list of items that hidden inside label control. it only show when mousecursor is in the controls area. it is like in the website where you can select in a list of items

Comment: Why would that not be a tooltip? Other, obviously, than that your browser isn't running on winforms. Tooltips can be loaded dynamically! and they can even be owner-drawn to allow for various fonts etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is best implemented by a `ToolTip`.

To add a `ToolTip` to a Control you usually do this:

- Add a `ToolTip` from the toolbox to the `Form`
- Now each control on the form as a new property field in the properties pane: `"ToolTip" on "yourToolTipName"`
- Set a tooltip text for each control you want to show a tool tip.

This is really simple.
Therefore many folks believe that that is all a `ToolTip` can do.

But it can be **created** and **modified** dynamically and **styled** in many ways. Showing a list of items is no problem at all..

To load it with data dynamically you code the `MouseHover` event of your `Label`:

```
private void yourLabel_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(yourLabel, yourData);
}
```

Of course you may want to call a function to load the right and current data for each of your `Labels`..: `string loadData(Label lbl)`.

If you want to you can easily **ownerdraw** the `ToolTip`. First code its `Popup` event:

```
private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
{
    toolTip1.BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;  // pick a Color if you want to
    toolTip1.OwnerDraw = true;      
}
```

Then the `Draw` event:

```
private void toolTip1_Draw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
{
    using (Font font = new Font("Consolas", e.Font.SizeInPoints))
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        e.DrawBorder();
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.ToolTipText, font, Brushes.DarkMagenta, e.Bounds);
    }
```

Note that the `ToolTip` will automatically resize to display the text. Also note that you can embed `\n` characters to create line breaks.

I chose the monospaced font `Consolas`, so I can create nicely aligned columns of text. Also note that if you want to enlarge the font you should add enough room via extra lines and/or space, this is because the **size** of the `ToolTip` area is calculated from its **original** font size and you can't pick a different Font for it.. See [here for a little more on that..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856991/changing-winforms-datagridview-tooltip-font/36857764?s=1|0.4854#36857764)

Also note that you do not need to set the property in the designer at all. The `MouseHover` does all you need..

Answer (score 1):

Create `ContextMenuStrip`, set event handlers for items:

```
var contextMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();
contextMenu.Items.Add("Item 1");
contextMenu.Items.Add("Item 2");
contextMenu.Items.Add("Item 3");
```

Your ControlLabel:

```
var label = new Label { Parent = this, BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle, Text = "Test" };
```

Show menu manually:

```
label.MouseHover += (s, e) =>
{
    contextMenu.Show(label, 0, label.Height);
};
```

Comment: this is what i'm looking for. simple to implement. but how to set the location of ContextMenuStrip based on label location

Comment: @HardDisk - `0, label.Height` is location relative to `label`.